# List all active sessions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I'm creating a page and I'd like to list all the logged in users that have active sessions. I'm thinking about reading off that data from mongodb session collection and parse the json. Is there better way to do it? If not, how do I parse json data in node?

Thanks

Comment: To parse JSON data use `JSON.parse()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: You should look into using something like [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) for modelling your db

Comment: Does your session collection contain a user id? If so, [find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) all user ids from the sessions collection then pass the array of ids to a nested find on the users collection to pull out their name, email etc.